# Mosquitto websockets security best practice

Tags: authentication, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a **Mosquitto** server running on which I activated the **websocket** listener. All works fine, I can subscribe/publish from an Angular application. I did not activate SSL from Mosquitto, but I did reverse-proxy using Nginx, effectively encrypting the websocket. I cannot access via `ws`, only via `wss`.

Now what is the best practice to restrict connection to the websocket to authenticated users only? Enabling the location to the outside world would make the MQTT server encrypted, but available to all. Is there a way to restrict connection to only authenticated user, and if so, how?

**EDIT**

Thanks to @john-romkey's clarifications, I can now activate authentication on Mosquitto side and enable a user that would be limited for the operations needed by the web client. The documentation also mentions *authentication plugins*, so I wonder if there is any token based authentication plugin that would remove the need for passing a user/pass to the front-end.

Answer (score 6):

SSL/TLS provides two functions:

First, it authenticates the server that the client is connecting to. This lets the client know that the server it connected to has access to the encryption certificates for the domain the client, which means that there's a very high probability that you're talking to the correct server and not a malicious imposter.

Second, it prevents third parties from eavesdropping on the connection. Malicious programs with access to the network data won't be able to decode the communications between the client and server and won't be able to tamper with it.

What it doesn't do is authenticate the client in any way.

So with the setup you've described, if I found your Mosquitto broker I could connect to the websocket and subscribe to any topic I wanted or publish to any topic I wanted, because the setup you described does nothing to control who can connect to the broker and what they can do once connected.

From a security perspective this is almost a **worst practice**.

Mosquitto provides two mechanisms for authenticating clients:

First, you can create a username and password for a client. Best practice would be to create unique usernames and passwords for each different potential client. Mosquitto provides an API that allows you to use a variety of different stores for the credentials, from a simple text file to full blown relational databases like Postgresql.

Second, you can create a client-side certificate which will uniquely identify the client.

These allow you to *authenticate* the client to access the broker.

Depending on the complexity of the pubsub network you're building over the MQTT broker, you should also consider restricting access to only the needed topics for each client.

This allows you to *authorize* the client to do specific work.

[Mosquitto's documentation](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html) discusses how to authenticate and authorize clients.

Comment: Thanks for the long explanation, it's always good to recall the basics. Nobody can listen to the traffic because it's encrypted, but anybody can talk to the server... Not being an expert in websockets, I think they don't offer authentication feature. If I activate user auth, does it apply also to wss? I will test and see. If so, I guess I'm just left with the issue of passing a user/pass to the web client in a secure way, so the connection to the wss can be authenticated. It's late, but I'll have a look here: https://github.com/mcollina/mosca/issues/603

Comment: Websockets is simply a transport layer. Authentication is handled by the MQTT broker that's using web sockets and is totally independent of whether you're running over websockets, TCP, SSL/TLS over TCP or some other layer, so Mosquitto definitely does authentication (and authorization) over wss.

Comment: Indeed, I made a quick test and had it work. I did not get it right first because the _ngx-mqtt_ library I am using has basic documentation. I realise afterwards that it’s actually a wrapper around _MQTT.js_ library, so most of the properties to create a client are described there. In a first phase I will create a simple user with limited rights only on the resources needed by the web page (that’s standard security practice anyway). Web page is encrypted, so is any resource served by it. If someone knows about auth plugins that can handle tokens, that can be step 2.

Comment: Given that I answered your question, please accept my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input @john-romkey, your comments rather than the answer itself helped me get more insight on my issue. Your answer can be summarized as "activate SSL and enable authentication", but very well explained. As I said later on, I'm still hopping someone can point me to a document explaining how to handle security tokens between a web client and Mosquitto, in order to avoid passing a clear user/pass to the client (albeit the web client being authenticated and encrypted as well). I'll edit my question in regards.

Comment: Don't charge your question. You posted one question here, you got an answer to that question. If you have a different question - security tokens and Mosquitto - post that as a separate question. (The answer to that is the Mosquitto has absolutely nothing to do with web authentication tokens, and that if you use a username and password over web sockets over SSL, they're passed encrypted - everything over web sockets and SSL will be encrypted because it's being sent over SSL).